# Argparse - How to parse a second argument when the first is not entered and reverting to defualt

Tags: python, argparse

I have the below function as part of a directory scanner:

```
def get_args():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Scan all files')
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Path to folder", nargs='?', default=cwd)
    parser.add_argument("print", help="Print file extensions", nargs='?', default=False)
    return parser.parse_args()


Scan /usr/Ari True
```

This will scan the specified folder and print out the list

```
Scan
```

Will scan the current working directory where I am in the terminal

```
Scan True
```

Does not work because it assumes I am entering a directory, How do I use the default of the first argument but specify the second?

[image]

Comment: `path` gets the first string, if any.  `print` gets a string only if 2 are provided.  `argparse` has no way of 'knowing' that 'True' is meant for the 2nd positional argument.  Why aren't you using `--print'` with `store_true`?

Comment: Do you realize that as defined `print` will be a `False` boolean, or a string, never a `True` boolean?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I don't want it to print anything unless I say True. So if I wanted to print I would write `Scan /some/directory True`, it will then print a more detailed result. If left to default False it will only print a minimal amount. It works, trust me. My issue is passing a second arg when it expects two.

Comment: You could look at `args.path`.  If it is 'True', rather than path like string, then assume your user wants to use the default path.  But why use `argparse` at all.  Just look at `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: As a general rule, using several `positionals` with `?' (or '*+') `nargs` is not a good idea.  The first argument is greedy, so you don't have good control over their assignment.  It assigns values by position, not by value.  Use flagged options if you want more control.  Or do your own parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
    def get_args():
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ScanDirecotry.py --path <path> --print (remove --print if you dont want to print.)')
        parser.add_argument("--path", help="Path to folder", default=cwd)
        parser.add_argument("--print", help="Print file extensions", action='store_true')
        return parser.parse_args()
```